# Does the Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Description of OUT Instruction contain errors?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

In Volume 2, CHAPTER 4 INSTRUCTION SET REFERENCE, M-U, the description of OUT Instruction has this sentence: 
"using the DX register as a source operand allows I/O ports from 0 to 65,535 to be accessed."

I think when using OUT instruction, the DX register is specify the IO port not the source operand.

Comment: The destination is the IO port, not DX

Comment: @Mat Thanks, I corrected my question.

Comment: How is DX not a source operand if it contains information used by the instruction?

Comment: @Mat The intel documentation describes it like this: Copies the value from the second operand (source operand) to the I/O port specified with the destination operand (first operand).

Comment: Yeah, it  calls it the destination operand in one sentence and the source operand in the next sentence. It has been this way since at least 2002.

Comment: @harold, according to the first sentence of the description, it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the manual attempts to say is true, even if the wording is a bit unclear.

When using an immediate parameter to specify the port number (like OUT imm8, AX), you are limited to ports 0-255 as the immediate operand is 8 bits.

When using DX to specify the port number (like OUT DX, EAX), all 65536 ports can be used.

The term 'source operand' is a bit misleading, as in the above example, the contents of EAX are output to the port specified by DX. So, the contents of DX specify the destination port number.

Comment: I get it, thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't call it correct—it calls the first operand the destination operand in one sentence and the source operand in the following sentence.

Comment: It's like a store instruction: all the registers involved are sources, and the actual destination is memory.  (Or in this case, IO address space).  Good point @prl on the inconsistent usage of "destination" (what the first operand normally is in x86) vs. "source" (based on what it's doing in a computer-science sense in this instruction).  At least the first usage of "destination" clarifies they mean the first operand. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/out.  If they said "the destination *port* can be specified ..." that would avoid the problem they have now.